# Dump remote database: Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers

Tags: mongodb, ssl, mongoimport, mongodump, mongorestore

I have a database in `www.myweb.io`, which has `SSL`. The version of mongo is `2.6.12` in the server: the version of mongo in local is `3.4.1`. I want to dump it into my local machine, modify it, and then restore back.

I tried

```
mongodump --host www.myweb.io --port 22 --username myname --password "mypassword"
```

and it gave me an error:

```
2017-11-20T20:57:07.775+0100    Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
```

Does anyone know what host and post I should set?

PS: in my localhost, I can use the following setting in Robo 3T to connect to the database:

1) under `Connection`, specify `localhost:27017`

2) under `SSH`, check `Use SSH tunnel`, specify `xxx.xx.xx.xx:22` as `SSH Address`

In `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myweb.io`, there is `listen 443 ssl`.

Comment: did any solution work for you? Please share it with me, as the solution below is not working for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

1. you are not connecting via SSL or TLS to the database.
2. Use an ssh tunnel to establish a connection to your mongodb

   `ssh -N -L 27018:localhost:27017 user@www.myweb.io`

you can specify `-f` to let ssh go in the background

3. Verify that the tunnel is working

Using mongodb

```
mongo --port 27018
```

Or telnet

```
telnet localhost 27018
```

4. dumping the database

   `mongodump --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27018 --db <dbName>`
5. restore it somewhere, do your modifications
6. dump your local modifications
7. reapply the local modifications remote for example with `mongorestore` or `mongoimport`